# Reformat the output

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am using the following command to get disk status:

> /opt/Navisphere/bin/naviseccli -h VNX5500-1-1 getdisk -state

the output i get is like:

```
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 0

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 2

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 4

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 6

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 8

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 10

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 12

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 14

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 16
```

I am trying to format the output to get one line for each bus. something like:

```
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 0   [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 2   [State: Enabled]
..
```

Comment: And what have you done to solve the problem apart from asking someone else to do it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^Bus/ {a=$0}; /^State/ {print a" ["$1, $2"]"}' file.txt
```

- `/^Bus/ {a=$0}`: if the line starts with `Bus`, save the line/record as variable `a`
- `/^State/ {print a" ["$1, $2"]"}`: if the line starts with `State`, save print the fields in desired format with `a` perpended

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 0

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 2

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 4

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 6

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 8

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 10

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 12

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 14

State:                   Enabled
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 16


% awk '/^Bus/ {a=$0}; /^State/ {print a" ["$1, $2"]"}' file.txt 
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 0 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 2 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 4 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 6 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 8 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 10 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 12 [State: Enabled]
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 14 [State: Enabled]
```